# Podspec failing on podfile pod imports

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I've created a `podspec` file for my project, which itself has a `podfile`.

Podfile looks something like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
```

Podspec file is also a standard setup:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "ConversationVC"
  s.version      = "1.0.1"
  s.summary      = "ConversationViewController, for messaging"
  s.homepage     = "[HOMEPAGE URL]"
  s.author       = { "Andrew Hart" => "[EMAIL ADDRESS]" }
  s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE'  }
  s.source       = { :git => "[GIT URL]", :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.platform     = :ios, '9.0'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.source_files  = 'Source/**/*.swift'
  s.frameworks   = 'UIKit'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
end
```

I'm using the `pod lib lint` command to make sure it passes the Podspec tests, and I'm getting this error:

> ERROR | xcodebuild: /Users/Andrew/Code/ConversationVC/Source/View/ConversationImageCell.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'FLAnimatedImage'

That file does have a `import FLAnimatedImage` line, referencing one of my pods, as do many other files in my project.

I did try using the pod in another project, giving the git url, and it succeeded, but when I built the workspace in Xcode, it gave me the same error to do with the missing framework of FLAnimatedImage.

I'm wondering how I'm supposed to handle this situation?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. My Xcode doesn't throw any errors, but `pod spec lint` always fails saying `error: no such module`.

Answer (score 4):

You should declare your dependencies in your podspec file too, like this:

```
s.dependecy "FLAnimatedImage", "~> 1.0"
```